# How to solve ASP.NET custom login page error?

Tags: c#, asp.net

In Login.aspx.cs file

The codes are following

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Web.Configuration;

namespace Leave_Management
{
    public partial class Login : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        //private string strcon = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=TAUFIQ-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=LM;Integrated Security=True");

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            conn.Open();
            string checkuser = "select UserName from [User] where UserName='" + TextBoxUN + "'";
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(checkuser, conn);

            int temp = Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar().ToString());


            if (temp == 1)
            {
                string checkpass = "select password from [User] where UserName='" + TextBoxUN + "'";
                SqlCommand passcom = new SqlCommand(checkpass, conn);
                string password = passcom.ExecuteScalar().ToString().Replace(" ", "");
                conn.Close();
                if (password == TextBoxPass.Text)
                {
                    Response.Redirect("Registration.aspx");
                }
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

An Error is showing as

> "NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code"
>
> **int temp = Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar().ToString());**

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: are you trying to convert string to int? this will cause error when string contains non-numeric values

Comment: another thing, is this TextBoxUN.Text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just simplify your code by checking both username and password from the SQL statement:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    conn.Open();
    string SQL = "select UserID from [User] where UserName=@UserName AND Password=@Password"; 
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(SQL, conn);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", TextBoxUN.Text);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", TextBoxPass.Text);
    SqlDataReader data = com.ExecuteReader();
    if (data.HasRows) // username and password match
    {
        conn.Close();
        Response.Redirect("Registration.aspx");
    }
    else
    {
        conn.Close();
        // display error here
    }
}
```

I assume that UserID is the primary key of your Users table. You can use other column names if you want.

I also used [parameters to avoid SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542510/how-do-i-create-a-parameterized-sql-query-why-should-i). Cheers!

Comment: **It works! Thanks for your code.** But something is missing: 
`string SQL = "select UserID from [User] where UserName=@UserName AND Password=@Password"; 
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(checkuser, conn);`
just have to replace SQL by checkuser.

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment, there are many things wrong with your code:

You are concatenating user-specified values into SQL queries. Don't do it, use parameters.

You are putting `TextBoxUN` into the SQL, you probably want `TextBoxUN.Text`. This is the reason you get null, since there is no user with that name.

You must take the value provided by `ExecuteScalar()` and check if it is null. Now it is, so you get a clear error about it.

Why get the username from the database with the username and then check for password? You can check for password and username with one query.

**Do not store passwords in cleartext in the database!** Use hash functions.

Comment: **Thank you very much! Yea I have to focus on coding properly.** I'm the beginner in programming. Would you suggest me how to learn programming by books or resource?

Answer (score 0):

if temp comes up as null, then you will get the error. I would try:

...

```
   int temp = 0;
   try {
       temp = Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
   } catch (exception) {}
```

...

Comment: Using exceptions is expensive, especially when you can just check if it is null.